# В Хроме не работает атрибут loop тега video

Tags: ubuntu, html5, видео

Появилась цель - написать видео-фон, не используя js, - и я реализовал это так:

```html
<video src="url" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>
```

Но проблема в том, что я пользователь Ubuntu и соответственно пишу с неё и работает во всех браузерах но в Chromium (ubuntu) не работает loop и сам вопрос в том, как правильно и/или кроссбраузерно написать loop для всех браузеров на всех ОС?

Comment: Используйте кнопку "вставить фрагмент" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа (Ctrl+K).

Comment: тэг видео выполняется во всех браузерах - я не прав ?

Comment: У вас отсутствует корретный URL, в результате страница пустая. Если найдёте *маленькое* (!) видео, доступное по HTTP и с постоянным URL, то можно сделать фрагмент. Цель оформления как фрагмента — для наглядной демонстрации проблемы.

Comment: понял спасибо - но редактировать я тоже могу чужие посты - мне бы ответ по сабжу

Comment: Это уже не ко мне, я тут дворником подрабатываю.

Comment: с юмором - это хорошо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Хроме цикличное воспроизведение (и вообще любая перемотка) работает, только если сервер поддерживает запросы по частям, то есть понимает заголовок `Range` и отвечает на него `206 Partial Content`. Это верно даже для мелких видео, которые полностью помещаются в памяти — никаких исключений, сервер обязан поддерживать `Range`.

Как вариант, можно городить костыли:

```
$('video').on('ended', function () {
  this.load();
  this.play();
});
```

См. [Google Chrome - HTML5 video will not loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop).

Если сервер поддерживает `Range`, то всё нормально работает:

```html
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" autoplay="" loop=""></video>
```

Хром может не дружить с локальными файлами и считать, что "сервер" не поддерживает `Range`. Но, так как обычно даже разработка ведётся с помощью сервера, а не локальных файлов, то проблема малоактуальна.

Comment: не работает -- поверил уже

Comment: @LenovoID Вы про хак? Может, тогда начать с partical content?

Comment: я не знаю с чего начать - мне просто нужно беспрерывное воспроизведение - стандартными тэгами -

Comment: @LenovoID Начните с сервера. Каким образом он у вас видео отдаёт? И что это вообще за зацикленный "видео-фон"?

Comment: да какой сервер - я верстаю на компе -на рабочем столе - и всё - index.html  -вот весь сервер - пока готового результата не будет то это на сервер не попадёт - это у меня ни первый проект - до этого писал легко - но тут встретился с такой фигнёй - не работает loop - я офигел если честно- не должно быть звука и controlpanel -просто фон видео - - можно реализовать на svg - но ни все браузеры это читают

Comment: @LenovoID Обновил ответ. В моём Хроме работает. Таки придётся использовать сервер, похоже.

Comment: Вот вы исправили загаловок - а ведь в нюм был смысл - не хром а хромиум и не винда а убунту

Comment: @LenovoID Хром и Хромиум — один движок. Убунту в теге (обратите внимание на заголовок страницы title — оно само добавляется). Теги в заголовках по-нормальному должны удаляться. Ну что, не работает что ли? Сейчас, Убунту запущу...

Comment: @LenovoID Запустил. Работает.

Comment: у меня не работает - я установил на вируалку винду - и в ней всё пашет - блин в  убунту в хромиум нет - почему то